# Integral with substitution, how they get to next step

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$2\int\frac{u^2}{u^2-4}\,du = 2\int\left(1+\frac{4}{u^2-4}\right)\,du$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdVDH.png)

Can someone please explain how they get from step on the left to the one on the right?

Comment: Put the integrand on the right over a common denominator. (Or use polynomial long division on the lefthand integrand to get a quotient and a remainder.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved it for me.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: add and substract $4$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\frac{u^2-4}{u^2-4} =1$ so then $1 +\frac{4}{u^2-4} = \frac{u^2-4}{u^2-4} + \frac{4}{u^2-4} = \frac{u^2}{u^2-4}$.